# tower of hanoi - a tuple of moves

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def hanoi(n,src,dsc,aux):
    if n == 1:
        print_move(src,dsc)
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,src,aux,dsc)
        print_move(src,dsc)
        hanoi(n-1,aux,dsc,src)

def print_move(src,dsc):
    print("Move the top disk from",src,"to",dsc)
```

I wish to change the above tower of hanoi code to output a tuple of moves that when executed in sequence will move all the disk from source pole to destination pole via the auxiliary pole. A disk move is defined as a pair of two numbers: the source pole and the destination pole. For example, `(1, 3)` indicates the move of a disk from the first pole to the third. Hence, `hanoi(2,1,3,2)` will output `((1,2),(1,3),(2,3))`

My approach is to create a global variable called `tup`, an empty tuple. Then whenever a new tuple move is created, it will be added to the `tup`. My problem is I do not know when I should return the value of `tup` and where inside the `hanoi` function I can put the `return` line.

Comment: You can't add things into a tuple, but you can instead return a list, and, if you wish, convert it to a tuple using `tuple(result)`, but I guess what you want is a list.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this in a recursive function is usually something like:

```
def hanoi(..., out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = [] # list to store output
    ...
    print_move(src, dsc)
    out.append((src, dsc)) # add result to output
    ...
    hanoi(..., out) # call recursively and ignore return
    ...
    return out # return output
```

(Note the use of `None` to avoid issues with mutable default parameters.)

And when calling:

```
results = hanoi(...)
```

This way a single list `out` is shared and added to by all levels of the recursive call. Each call ignores the return value from deeper calls, as they can access the same list anyway, but the caller at the top level gets back the output from all levels.

A list is a better idea for the storage than a tuple, as lists are mutable, but a two-tuple for each move seems sensible:

```
results == [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your solution. Can you explain it in term of the hanoi function?

Comment: I have changed some of the names, but the principle is independent of the exact nature of the recursive function.